# Insertion mark for ListView in WPF

Tags: wpf, insertion

I need create Insertion mark for my ListView during Drag&Drop system.
(as Powerpoint). I'm found  Insertion mark in [**Componentowl**](http://www.componentowl.com/documentation/better-listview/data/chapter-drag-drop.html) but I need create my own insertion mark for Drag&Drop in ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how it should be done in theory:

Handle `MouseLeftButtonDown`, `MouseMove` and `MouseLeftButtonUp` events of the draggable element. When the mouse button is pressed, you need to `capture mouse` on the element in order to get `MouseMove` events while dragging and `release the capture` when button is released.

In `MouseMove` eventhandler you need to find out elements under mouse and show the 'insertion mark' in a `Popup` control or in `Adorner Layer` (Popup control is used to show content in top of everything) and update its position.

Alternativley, you may use `DragEnter`, `DragOver` and `DragLeave` eventhandlers on the drop target element to whow the insertion mark in popup or adorner layer.

You may read this article: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2007/07/12/drag-drop-in-wpf-explained-end-to-end.aspx

or this article: https://cuteprogramming.wordpress.com/2010/12/19/drag-and-drop-reordering-in-wpf-listview/ which refers to this article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ListViewDragDropManager.aspx

here is another solution:
https://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/06/17/wpf-drag-drop-adorner/